# Deck Ledger with Manufactured Wood Joists

Tags: deck, ledger

My house came with a second story deck added by the previous owner.  The ledger is attached directly over the stucco and is attached to a 1/2 in plywood band board with deck screws.  The band board caps the end of manufactured wood joists (MWJ) that are mounted on a 3X12 beam.  I don't trust this construction (its not up to code in so many ways)and want to cut the stucco and install galvanized brackets to the support beam that will hold a new ledger up and against the band board at the same height.   The deck framing is solid and I would like to keep the current configuration as the posts of a free standing deck would be create access issues.

Has anyone dealt with attaching a ledger to the beam supporting the MWJ.  Any other thought on how to fix this?

Thanks, Mike

Comment: Some photos might be helpful

Comment: Even a rough drawing would work.